# Kendo Chart Export to Pdf in IE9

Tags: kendo-ui

kendo UI chart API not working in ie9.Its working fine in chrome, firefox and ie10.I didn't get any exception in ie9.simply page refreshed.please see below code is not working in ie9

```
$("#btnExportToPDFView").click(function () {           
            // Convert the DOM element to a drawing using kendo.drawing.drawDOM
            kendo.drawing.drawDOM($(".content-wrapper"))
            .then(function (group) {
                // Render the result as a PDF file
                return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(group, {
                    paperSize: "auto",
                    margin: { left: "1cm", top: "1cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "1cm" }
                });
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                // Save the PDF file
                kendo.saveAs({
                    dataURI: data,
                    fileName: "Reports.pdf"
                    //proxyURL: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export"
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Consider posting a minimal amount of code that will not work in IE9 but will work in others.  Questions with code are more likely to receive attention and answers.

Answer (score 3):

The kendo documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo#methods-saveAs) says that IE9 requires the use of the proxyURL that you have commented out in your code. You will need a service that can "return the decoded file with set "Content-Disposition" header."

Here is an example of a web service that you could use:

```
var response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
var request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;

var fileName = request.Params["fileName"];
var contentType = request.Params["contentType"];
var encodedString = request.Params["base64"];
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedString);

response.Clear();
response.ClearHeaders();
response.ContentType = contentType;

response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName);
response.OutputStream.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length);

response.Flush();
response.End();
```